# How to find/replace and increment a matched number only with awk?

Tags: awk

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348899/15603477
I do understand the following answer.
`sed -r 's/(.*)(\?cache_version=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' file`
But I wonder how to do it in awk.
To transform `barbaz?cache_version=3fooooo` to `barbaz?cache_version=4fooooo`
The `test1` file content as

```
ello
barbaz?cache_version=3fooooo
bye
```

The condition is find line contain `cache_version=` then increase the numeric value in the matched line by 1.
I even fail to locate the matched numeric value, not even mention increase the numeric value.

So far I only locate the specific line by
`awk '{if(/cache_version=([[:digit:]+])/) print $1}' < test1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number is always an integer number:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="=" }
/cache_version/{ match($NF, /^[0-9]+/); $NF=($NF+1) substr($NF, RLENGTH+1) }1' infile
```

in the BEGIN{} block we sets the input **F**ield **S**eparator and also **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator to single equal `=` char;

then here we are doing `awk '/pattern-matching(regexp)/ { "actions" }`, which actions within `{...}` block will be only runs for the line matching with the regexp `cache_version`;

the [match(s, r [, a]) function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), return the position in *`s`* where the regular expression *`r`* occurs, or zero if *`r`* is not present, and set the values of *RSTART* (where the starting position of the regular expression *`r`* occur) and *RLENGTH* (the length in characters of the matched substring/regexp).

Note: I used `$NF+1` to force awk to do string to integer conversion as *I know that digits are at the starting position of the $NF (while you could sue *`substr($NF,1, RLENGTH)+1`* too)*, then get the reset of the $NF from the *`substr($NF, RLENGTH+1)`*.

Note: change regex in the `match($NF, /^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/)`, to match almost all type of digits (you might want to use proper printing controls too, see [OFMT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match` function in `gawk` to capture groups into an array and print out each element while incrementing the captured digit:

```
echo 'barbaz?cache_version=3fooooo' | gawk 'match($0, /(.*cache_version=)([[:digit:]]+)(foo.*)/, a) {print a[1] a[2]+1 a[3]}'
```